# Backreferences to constituents of a group consisting of a fixed number of repetitions

Tags: regex, perl, backreference, repeat

I want to find a group that is repeated x times after each other, eg, five times a letter-digit combo separated by a space. I can use a simple repetition syntax, eg `(?:\w\d ){5}`.

I then want to replace the space in this 5x letter-digit with something else. For this, I try to backreference each of the letter-digit combos (without the space) by placing parentheses around it: `(?:(\w\d) ){5}`. Unfortunately, all five are store in `$1`, ie, `$1` gets overwritten every time it matches.

So, is there a way to avoid this overwriting? Or is there a way to replace something only in a substring?

EDIT:

Example input string: `A1 A3 A4 B6 ::: A1 A3 A4 C5 B6`

Desired output string: `A1 A3 A4 B6 ::: A1-A3-A4-C5-B6`

That means, replace the space only if there are five of them. Implemented in Perl.

Comment: Some sample input and output, as well as what language you're working in would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to solve the problem, something like this works

`$string = 'A1 A3 A4 B6 ::: A1 A3 A4 C5 B6';`
`$string =~ s/(\w\d(?: \w\d){4})/$_=$1; tr{ }{-}; $_/eg;`
`print "'$string'\n";`

Otherwise, group repetition in Perl does overwrite the capture buffer every loop.

I don't know if another programatic way is possible.

**edit**

If you want to cover multiple spaces between character, add a + quantifier and the tr///`s` - squash duplicate replacements in tr///.
`s/(\w\d(?: +\w\d){4})/$_=$1; tr{ }{-}s; $_/eg;`

If you have fancier replacements you can always double up the regex with a callback style
equivalent

```
$string =~ s/(\w\d(?: +\w\d){4})/fixspaces($1)/eg;
sub fixspaces {
   my $buf = shift;
   $buf =~ s/ +/-/g;
   $buf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. That one can drop in expression in Perl at a lot of unlikely locations (like this `$_=$1; tr{ }{-}s; $_` via the `e` option) is something that is highly useful.

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly and inflexible, but for your sample input, if it really is always five, and if your sample input never varies, this should work:

```
s/(\w\d) +(\w\d) +(\w\d) +(\w\d) +(\w\d) */$1-$2-$3-$4-$5/
```

Comment: That is where I was coming from, the main issue for me is inflexibility (which I naturally can always solve with a loop in Perl).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
sub substitute{
    $substr=shift;
$substr=~s/\s/-/gi;
return $substr;
}

$test="hello a1 b2 c3 d4 e5 testing";
$test=~s/((?:\w\d\s){4})(\w\d)\s/&substitute($1).$2." "/egi;
print $test;
```

Comment: (Just change the quantifier to the number of hyphenated combos you want, if you have a sequence of 8 change it to 7 etc.)

Comment: ... and is effectively exactly the same as Sin posted, nm